# Switch back from Cloudflare SSL - 301 Back to http?

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https, cloudflare

I need to know how put a 301 Redirect in my htaccess which points https back to http. Can you help?

I see plenty of posts for going from http to https, but not in reverse!

I am switching back from Cloudflare and their SSL back to normal http - my search rankings never recovered after the switch and so just taking it back to normal.

Comment: You'll need a valid SSL certificate (Cloudflare or otherwise) to do so. Using Cloudflare shouldn't hurt your SEO - are you *sure* this is the cause?

Comment: I already had the SSL up from Cloudflare running for 1 month, I have removed it and switched my DNS back. Now need a 301 to point the Https version back to http

Comment: Be sure you don't have `strict transport security` (`HSTS`). If you do, you cannot go back, basically.

Comment: @Mike You'll need an SSL on your server to do that. Has to be valid HTTPS to get to the redirect.

Comment: **Don't use a 301 redirect**. If you previously used a 301 redirect when going from HTTP to HTTPS then there is **no way** to reverse this for anyone whom has visited your site short of re-installing their browsers. Man up and get an SSL certificate.

Comment: Google ranks sites with SSL certs as higher: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html

Furthermore, CloudFlare won't affect SEO: https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-and-seo/

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Should do the trick in an .htaccess

Edit: last part fell off. 
And indeed if you have no valid ssl the redirect will never get served without an error .. ( letsencrypt has free ssl certs...)

Comment: No, that will only work if you add `[R]` on the end of the rewrite rule - and is predicated on an ability to decrypt an HTTPS request and encrypt the response (i.e. have a working TLS cert installed) which the OP no longer has.